# php + mysql query returning only a single row (std class) from class function

Tags: php

Can you tell me why this returns only the last row of my query?
As you see I'm extracting as std class. Also I already tried different approaches like a foreach key=>value inside the while but it does not help. I can't populate $out correctly.

```
class myclass {

    function Query($sql){

    $results = $this->db->query($sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)<1){   
        throw new Exception('NoResults');       
    }   

    $out = new stdClass;        
    while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){

        $out = $r;  
    } 

    return $out;
    $out = null;
    }

}

}

---------------

$client = new myclass;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
    $q = $client->Query($sql);


    print_r($q);
```

Comment: In your while loop, you are doing this `$out = $r`. You are overwritting the value of `$out` on each iterations, then return it. That's why you are getting the last value

Comment: Note that the line below `return $out;` won't be executed, since `return` *breaks* the execution of the function

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$out` at every iteration of the `while`, so you'll have only the last result in the return. You could use an array and append the results (it could be an array of stdClass objects), and then you'll be able to work with it with a simple loop

```
class myclass {

    function Query($sql){

        $results = $this->db->query($sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results)<1){   
            throw new Exception('NoResults');       
        }   

        //copied this piece of code from @Berto99 answer from this same question
        $out = []; // array that will hold all the objects
        while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){
            array_push($out, $r);  // add to the array the current object
        } 
        return $out; //return the array with the objects
    }  

}


---------------

$client = new myclass;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
$q = $client->Query($sql);


foreach($q as $resultLine){
    //do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: I tried this but does not help:  while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){
  
  foreach($r as $k=>$v){
   $out->$k = $v;
  }
   
 }

Comment: Nono, that's wrong like that. First you have to append each `$r` to `$out`, like @Berto99 's answer below, and then return `$out`, from there you can easily work with `$q` with a foreach

Comment: can you show me? I can't get how to append objects to a std class like this

Comment: @Robert i've edited my answer adding some code. By default `mysqli_result::fetch_object` will return and `stdClass` read docs here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change those lines:

```
$out = new stdClass;        
while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){
    $out = $r;  
}
```

to those ones:

```
$out = []; // array that will hold all the objects
while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){
    array_push($out, $r);  // add to the array the current object
} 
return $out; //return the array with the objects
```

Comment: @Robert sorry but what you want inside that object?

Comment: @Robert _“i want to return a std class, that's the point”_ - that doesn’t even make much sense to begin with here. Using an object can make sense for a single record from your database - but returning all of them “as a std class”, that makes very little sense. You want to work with multiple values here, so that should involve an array at some point or other. Arrays are what you can easily loop over - trying to push all of your records into one std class instance somehow, will only give you trouble when it comes to actually working with this data later one.

Answer (score 0):

Your $r is object. You dont need stdClass.  You need to add your objects to $out array.

```
function Query($sql)
{
    $results = $this->db->query($sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) < 1) {   
       throw new Exception('NoResults');       
    }   

    $out = new stdClass;
    $i=0;
    while ($r = $results->fetch_object()){
        $out->{$i} = $r;  
        $i++
    } 

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I want to return a stdclass. Tried this return (object) $out; with not success

Comment: Any idea. Why  (object) $out is not returning a stdclass ?

Comment: Just realized that if I use the array without trying to convert it to std class, it does not work (PHP Notice:  Undefined index). I'm lost.

Comment: It does not work. PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass:

Comment: this is the dump of the returned object ($q = $client->Query($sql); var_dump($q) ) with the code above: object(stdClass)#5 (1) { [""]=> object(stdClass)#6 (10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(15) "gancio"  }}

Comment: it seems that you dont have $i variable from my code before your while loop.